# Updating all fields seperate in database with 1 button

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a list of items stored in the database, i print these items in a table But the name of every item can be changed in an input field, the problem is when i change the names of every item and press the button "update" then the last value "name" gets updated on every item. How is it possible to update every item with hes unique name? this is my code i hope the description is clear.

View

```
<form role="form" action="<?php echo base_url();?>CRUD/voegcategorietoe" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             <table class="table table-striped">
                 <?php foreach($allGallery as $row) { ?>
                 <tr>
                     <td><img height="80" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/uploads/<?php echo $row->gallery_img; ?>" alt=""/></td>
                     <td>name: <input type="text" class="form-control kort" name="name" value="<?php echo $row->order; ?>" required></td>
                     <td>Titel: <?php echo $row->titel; ?></td>
                     <td>Period: <?php echo $row->period; ?></td>
                     <td>Size: <?php echo $row->size; ?></td>
                     <td>Info: <?php echo $row->info; ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo anchor("site/delete/$row->gallery_id",'X') ?></td>
                 </tr>
                 <?php }?>
             </table> 
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Update</button>
         </form>
```

Controller

```
 function updategallery() {
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';
    $config['max_width']  = '3024';
    $config['max_height']  = '3768';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    }   

    $datap = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    $data = array();
    if( $this->input->post('name') != "" ) $data['name'] = $this->input->post('name');
    $this->Cms_model->update_gallery($data);    
    redirect('home#gallery','refresh');     

 }
```

Model

```
 function update_gallery($data)  
{  
    $this->db->update('tblgallery', $data);
}
```

Comment: give your input field `name="name[]"`

Comment: Alright i now get a array of strings in my controller. Is there anyhting else i need to do? Because i get an array to string error.

Comment: if i got your question; you need to have a view that send your data with ajax to your controller **then** get your data and convert them to array and pas it to your model **at the end** insert your array with `$this->db->update_batch();` see this document http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update